# Write input to console using C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, command-prompt, windows-console

Let's say I am changing the password of a user,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("net user myUsername *");
  return 0;
}
```

and when run this program, I get back

```
Type a password for the user:
```

How do I write to the console with a function without manually typing on to the keyboard? Is there some function like

```
writeConsoleWindow("myPass");
submitConsole();
```

Comment: Why don't you use the API

Comment: i need automation, why would I?:)  @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Er, if you want to do something programmatically, use the API

Comment: I believe there should be a way.

Comment: The first part of the accepted answer from Remy Lebeau is completely wrong for the problem posed in the question. Using a pipe wouldn't work to write to the password prompt of net.exe, since this program reads only from the console. It requires being attached to the same console (e.g. allocating a hidden console before creating the child) and calling `WriteConsoleInput`, if someone is inclined to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateProcess()` to launch `cmd.exe` (which is what `system()` does) with a redirected STDIN handle, then you can write data to `cmd` in your code. See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx).

However, in the specific case of `net user` commands, you should be using functions like [`NetUserGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654.aspx), [`NetUserSetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370659.aspx), [`NetUserChangePassword()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370650.aspx), etc instead.

Comment: In this case the OP needs to run net.exe which runs net1.exe. Your first suggestion will not work because `net1!GetPasswdStr` hard-codes calling `GetConsoleMode`, `SetConsoleMode`, and `ReadConsole` on the standard input handle in order to read the password securely from the console and only the console. This fails for a pipe, and it stupidly creates a blank password. You would need to be attached to its console and drive it with [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput).

Comment: Though in this case you would more simply just pass it in the command line as `net user myUsername myPass`.